# How do I exclude a url in keycloak 4.6?

Tags: keycloak

```
keycloak:
  enabled: true
  public-client: true
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8180/auth
  realm: realm
  resource: test
  securityConstraints:
  - authRoles:
    - test
    securityCollections:
    - name: test
      patterns:
      - /test/demo/*
```

this config can include /test/demo/*.

but i want exclude /test/info and include  /test/demo/*.

keycloak version 4.6.0.Final

Answer (score 0):

```html
keycloak:
  enabled: true
  public-client: true
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8180/auth
  realm: realm
  resource: test
  securityConstraints:
  - authRoles:
    - test
    securityCollections:
    - name: test
      patterns:
      - /test/demo/*
```

```html
keycloak:
  enabled: true
  public-client: true
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8180/auth
  realm: realm
  resource: test
  securityConstraints:
  - authRoles:
    - test
    securityCollections:
    - name: test
      patterns:
      - /test/demo/*
  - authRoles:
    security-collections:
    - name: test
      patterns:
      - /test/demo/login
      - /test/demo/info
```

this config can exclude /test/demo/login and /test/demo/info